# python code that activates a workbook and run the vba code?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have this code that can run VBA or macro code from python but only when the workbook is active, means i have manually to open the workbook before i run the python code.

```
import xlwings as xw
import win32com.client

xl_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl_app = xw.App(visible=False,add_book=False)
wk = xw.books.open(r'C:\Users\afoto001.000\Desktop\All projects\FS\VBA\Perform.xlsm')
wk.api.Unprotect(Password='')
macro = wk.app.macro("Module1.shappen")
macro()
print('yes')
```

I'd like to completely automate the process, with no manual contact with the workbook. Is there a python package or something that I can use to execute the code and have it activate the workbook so that the code can run the marco? Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Did you try openpyxl?  https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: There's `wk.activate()` if your VBA code depends on this, otherwise that shouldn't be required. OpenPyXL is only a solution if you can rewrite the VBA logic in pure Python that reads and/or writes to the workbook, but it wouldn't be able to run VBA.

Comment: Thanks @FelixZumstein

Comment: Thanks @Amiga500 that cant run VBA code